# ElasticSearch Nest Boolean Query producing different scoring

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm doing a proof of concept for a client and I'm currently running some simple queries to aid in this proof of concept.

I'm doing a very simple boolean query which should produce the same score for all documents as it's just on one field but it's giving different scoring.

The query is below

```
var response = client.Search<TblRace>(s => s
                     .Query(q => q
                     .Bool(b => b
                     .Must(
                             m => m.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Handicap).Value(true)))
                          )
                          )
                    .Take(300)
                    .Explain()
               );
```

I know the suggestion would be if you want consistent scoring in this fashion to use the filter but this is just a simplistic way of me checking how scoring is produced.

My final proof of concept will actually look at the "Handicap" field and boost it if it's true but still include it if it's false.

I'll eventually have a host of fields which act in this manner to produce a ranked system based on lots of boolean inputs where it is boosted if it matches the user's preferences but still include the results if it doesn't.

The question is: Why am I getting inconsistent scoring? I've tried to examine the explain results but they mean nothing to me for me to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out this is to do with sharding.

Indexes are stored across multiple shards and they're responsible for their own scoring.

It may well be the case that my small dataset which I've uploaded (200 records) isn't enough to produce a score which is consistent.

3 possible answers are:

1. Increase the amount of documents indexed
2. Use .SearchType(SearchType.DfsQueryThenFetch) - This performs an
   initial query then merges the results and standardises the scoring
3. Set the maximum amount of shards to 1 when creating your index. This
   is only applicable if you plan on only ever having a small dataset
   as it slows down the query